# Logistic Regression with fixed Effects and Interaction Term

Tags: r, logistic, maximum-likelihood, fixed-effects-model

I am trying to fit a logistic regression model in order to analyze if the fuel type has an influence on how powerplants respond to droughts (e.g. are Nuclear Powerplants more likely to shut down (generation = 0) when experiencing water scarcity.

I created a panel dataset with around 130 Plants and 230 Time Periods which can be found [here](https://we.tl/t-8Jl4UUYWKN)

The panel mainly contains:

- powerplant ( a column with powerplant names)
- resource type (a column with resource types: Coal, Nuclear, Oil, Gas, Hydro Pumped Storage, Hydro WaterReservoir/River)
- date (a column filled with dates of observations, observed on every 1st, 11th and 21nd of a month)
- quantity (a column reflecting the average quantity produced per day by the powerplant in the interval specified by the date)
- any_gen (a column that specifies whether on a given day there was any generation or not)
- drought index (a variable that specifies the drought level, where positive values indicate more drought, negative values indicate less and between -1 and 1 is normal conditions)

My first analysis is a FE Regression:

```r
library(fixest)
ihs <- function(x) {
  y <- log(x + sqrt(x ^ 2 + 1))
  return(y)
}
reg <- feols(ihs(daily_quantity) ~ drought_index : 
         resource_psr_type_def + CDD + HDD + solar + wind + imports + 
         exports| name + date, data=panel)
```

Where utilizing the colon : instead of the asterix * because I am not interested in the coefficients of the fuel type or drought index alone and : allows me to interpret without dropping one fuel type as a reference category.

**Now to my actual question:** I would want to do the exact same thing for a logistic or probit  regression, for which I initially did this:

```r
reg_logit1 <- glm(
  gen_any ~ drought_index:resource_psr_type_def + CDD + HDD + solar + 
              wind + imports + exports + name + date, 
              data = panel, family = "binomial"
)
```

The results i get for the K coefficients from drought_index x fueltype_k perfectly support my research hypothesis, however - I also get a coefficient for each powerplant.
I have also tried using the fixest package where fixed effects are incorporated:

```r
reg_logit_FE1 <- feglm(gen_any ~  
        drought_index:resource_psr_type_def + CDD + HDD + solar + 
        wind + imports + exports | name + date, data=panel)
```

This leaves me mainly with insignificant results but at least the right direction - what is the difference between these two? Is this due to the incidental parameters problem and inconsistency of the maximum likelihood estimator?

I came across many sources saying that because of this, fixed effects are not typically used in logistic regression, which led me to try the following regression that excludes both date and name:

```r
reg_logit2 <- glm(
  gen_any ~ drought_index : resource_psr_type_def + CDD + HDD + 
                solar + wind + imports + exports, data = panel,
                family = "binomial"
)
```

This however flips the signs of almost all coefficients, which opposes the findings in the fixed effects regression, making it more similar to the coefficients when using no fixed effects in `reg`.

I would appreciate guidance on how to move forward here, which model is reliable and what do i need to be cautious about.